# Return values from one function work properly, returns from the second do not reflect the correct value

Tags: c, function

Basically I have two functions. Function 1, calculateGamma returns angleY. This is my prototype for the function:

```
double calculateGamma(int l1, int l2, int l3) {
    double eqn1Numer = (pow(l1, 2) + pow(l2, 2) - pow(l3, 2)); 
    double eqn1Denom = 2 * l1 * l2;
    double angleY = acos(eqn1Numer / eqn1Denom);
    return angleY;
}
```

I call the function with this statement:

```
angleYres = calculateGamma(l1, l2, l3);
```

My second function, radiusMethod1, uses the return value from calculateGamma.
(I have checked and the actual value for angleYres is correct, and I can print it in main.)

This is my second function:

````
double radiusMethod1(int angleYres, int l1, int l2, int l3) {
    printf("Angle Y: %lf\n", angleYres);
    printf("%d %d %d", l1, l2, l3);```
}
````

If I print the angleY in main, the value is 1.44568. If I print angleYres (what I've defined angleY as in function main) within the function radiusMethod1 it returns 0.0000. This confuses me, as l1, l2, and l3 all print to the correct output: 200, 250, 300 and these are three values I've gained from another function.

My question is: how can I get the return value angleY from calculateGamma to be used in function radiusMethod2?

I've tried reassigning the function using the same method I used for l1, l2, l3 and it does not seem to work the same way; which is confusing to me as I think I am using the same method.

Here is my raw code with troubleshooting comments/prints ect

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int readLength(void) {
    int length;
    printf("Please enter a side (largest value last): ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    return length;
}

double calculateGamma(int l1, int l2, int l3) {
    double eqn1Numer = (pow(l1, 2) + pow(l2, 2) - pow(l3, 2)); // Equation 1 calculation
    double eqn1Denom = 2 * l1 * l2;
    double angleY = acos(eqn1Numer / eqn1Denom);
    return angleY;
}

double radiusMethod1(int angleYres, int l1, int l2, int l3) {
    printf("Angle Y: %lf\n", angleYres);
    printf("%d %d %d", l1, l2, l3);
}

/*double radiusMethod2(int l1, int l2, int l3) {
    double valS = (.5) * (l1 + l2 + l3); // calculates value under the square root
    double eqn2Numer = (pow(valS * (valS - l1) * (valS - l2) * (valS - l3), 0.5));
    double radiusT_Circ = eqn2Numer / valS; 
    return radiusT_Circ;
}

void printResults(double angleYres, double radiusMethod1, double radiusMethod2) {
    printf("Angle Gamma: %lf", angleYres);
    printf("Method 1: %lf", radiusMethod1);
    printf("Method 2: %lf", radiusMethod2);
}*/

int main() {
    int length;
    int l1, l2, l3, angleY;
    double angleYres, radius1res, radius2res;
    // Gets user lengths and assigns them to l1, l2, l3
    l1 = readLength();
    l2 = readLength();
    l3 = readLength();
    // Calculates angle Y
    angleYres = calculateGamma(l1, l2, l3);
    printf("Angle Y: %lf\n", angleYres);
    // Calculates radius using method 1
    radius1res = radiusMethod1(angleYres, l1, l2, l3);
    printf("\n%lf", radius1res);
```

I expect angleY to output to ~1.4 in function radiusMethod1, however it outputs to 0.0000 within the function and -nan(ind) in main.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` if using gcc or clang) and pay attention to them.

Comment: `radiusMethod1` doesn't have a return statement...

Comment: `double radiusMethod1(int angleYres...` --> `double radiusMethod1(double angleYres...` ?

Comment: @4386427 I am trying to use the return statement from calculateGamma to print angleY within radiusMethod1 as I need to use angleY to calculate radiusMethod1.

Comment: oh my god.. I am so stupid. of course I didn't use the same type... thanks. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration of `double radiusMethod1(int angleYres, int l1, int l2, int l3)` angleYres should be a double, not an int.

The same problem occurs with declaring `angleY` as an int in the main function. Here it also should be a double.